# Remounting HOME

Tags: command-line, mount

I have my "/home" partition formatted as ext4 and mounted at "dev/sdc1" and occasionally have a strange problem coming up that looks a lo[t like this bug that I found here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/438379).

A little more than half way down the bug I linked to above, there was a work-around offered for remounting the drive "on the fly" when this happens.

So, before I try executing this command I wanted to run it by someone more proficient than me to be sure I won't "muck up" my system. Here it is:

```
mount -t ext4 -o rw,remount /dev/sdc1 /home
```

I still consider myself a bit new to Linux (about two years). I get the part about mounting the home partition as ext4 with read/write permissions, but wanted to be sure the last part `/dev/sdc1 /home` was mounting sdc1 'as' "/home".

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's what it does.  If you are not aware of manual pages, you should be (try `man mount`).

You almost certainly have a line in `/etc/fstab` about `/home` linking it to that device.  If so, you can just use:

```
mount -o rw,remount /home
```

And the defaults from fstab will be used.

You probably don't have that actual bug unless you are using a system that has not been updated in years.  However, if you have a problem with the partition being read-only, that remount command should fix it.

Adding `-v` before the `-o` may give you slightly more informative output.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I created [a new question] [1] related to this one if you would also like to help me with the underlying issue.

[1]:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61987/home-is-read-only-after-coming-out-of-screensaver-intermittent

Answer (score 0):

A filesystem gets remounted read-only by the kernel if something fishy is detected, be careful! Check your logs (var/log/*`) for any reports of disk failure or filessytem messup. If something says the disk is failing **turn the machine off inmediately**. When hard disks start failing, they normally only have a few hours of life left. Get a replacement, and salvage whatever you can from the ailing disk. If you are brave, you could try reformatting and using it for something less critical (spam storage, ... :-).

If it is "just" filesystem strangeness, a round of `fsck(8)` (probably run in single user/maintenance mode, or even from a rescue disk) is in order.

Update everything (particularly the kernel) and check that the installed packages are OK, reinstall whatever looks strange (in RPM based systems, the check is `rpm -Va`. It takes quite some time to check everything; it also complains without apparent reason on a lot of packages, but that I can't help with).