# /home is Read Only after coming out of screensaver (intermittent)

Tags: mount, home, readonly

I am using Linux Mint 13 (Maya) and I have my "/home" partition formatted as ext4 and mounted at "dev/sdc1".

Occasionally I have a strange problem coming up that looks a lot [like this bug that I found here](http://pastebin.com/6XEkKsuK). Well, at least the part that refers to the "/home" partition becoming "read only" when it wakes up from the screen saver.

I will be working around the problem by issuing the following command:

```
mount -t ext4 -o rw,remount /dev/sdc1 /home
```

However, what I would like to know is how to really troubleshoot this issue (a system log?) to narrow down what might be causing the problem.

Pertinent Points:

- I just did a fresh Mint installation last week.
- I just bought a new Western Digital terabyte drive to use as /home
- Three or four days before the problem arose. I installed the kernel with PAE support.
- This entire system (minus the new WD drive) was working great with
  Ubuntu.

Thanks,

.................................

~ After Two Weeks ~

.................................

Ok so it's been two weeks since I posted this and I am still trying to resolve this issue, and it's "holding me up" on some other things that I want to do however I am a happy father of two toddlers that give me good reason not to poor all of my time and effort in resolving this. In the meantime I just booted into Puppy Linux which resolves my noncritical computer use needs.

I have a couple of ideas that I am considering and I'll give you my reasons for these ideas as well.

1) I wonder if my fstab has anything to do with this since I installed Mint using my 1 Terabyte drive as my entire "/home" and later resized it so that only half of it was used as home. However [my fstab](http://pastebin.com/6XEkKsuK) looks correct as far as I can tell.

2) When I was copying my old backup (of /home) to my new /home, I had a problem with the permissions (I was copying as root) so I did a "chown -R" for the entire /home. ... That was a few weeks ago at this point so I am trying to remember the exact command that I used and whether I did that before or after the resize of the partition.

And just in case it is of any value, I've also included a copy of my [mtab](http://pastebin.com/7LmL661j) and my "[proc/mounts](http://pastebin.com/am6gG6wt)".

...............................................

~ Question Improvement I ~

...............................................

My short (and to the point) question would be, "Would that [errors=remount,ro] entry have stayed there after a re-installation?; 'and' would that entry being there affect what the OS does currently?" ... When I first installed Mint a few weeks ago I used an old 80Gig IDE drive as the "/" and that drive turned out to be bad.

Ok so, with the idea that this might help you (to help me), here is a little history.

When I first installed Mint a few weeks ago my drive layout looked like this:

- "/" installed on sdb1 --> 80Gig IDE (single partition)
- "swap" installed on sda1 --> 40GB IDE (single partition)
- "/home" installed on sdc1 --> 1TB SATA (single partition)

I had two IDE drives and one SATA. At that time sdb1 belonged to the 80Gig IDE drive (where "/" was installed) that had turned out to be a bad drive which I replaced with a 80Gig SATA drive and then reinstalled Mint.

During the reinstallation I resized sda1 so the SWAP was now only 10GB. And 'after' the Mint reinstallation I resized sdc1 so that "/home" was half a Terabyte. So my new (current) layout looks like this:

- "/" installed on sdb1 --> 80Gig SATA (single partition)
- "swap" installed on sda1 --> 10GB Partition on IDE drive
- "/home" installed on sdc1 --> 1/2TB on SATA drive

...............................................

~ Other Notes to Consider ~

...............................................

I used "HD Tune" on UBCD (Ultimate Boot CD) to diagnose all of the drives that I am currently using. "HD Tune" is what I had used to verify (after it started failing) that the original 80GB IDE had twelve bad sectors. ... So after that experience I tested all the drives that I was using including the brand new (less than six weeks old) Western Digital terabyte drive that I am currently using as my "/home" assignment.

Comment: Is the PAE kernel on Mint the same version number as the kernel you were using before that? Looking in `/boot` or `/lib/modules` may provide you with a clue if you are not sure.

Comment: Yup, I was really careful to stare and compare the numbers for a few minutes before I made the decision. I was really hesitant to make any kind of a change like that so that was a reason for the extra caution on my part.

Also spent about half an hour googling around on the advantages of different kernels that were offered before I settled on the PAE one.

Comment: The contents of /boot:

2012 abi-3.2.0-23-generic ,,
2012 abi-3.2.0-23-generic-pae ,,
2012 config-3.2.0-23-generic ,,
2012 config-3.2.0-23-generic-pae ,,
9:53 grub ,,
6:05 initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic ,,
9:53 initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae ,,
2011 memtest86+.bin ,,
2011 memtest86+_multiboot.bin ,,
2012 System.map-3.2.0-23-generic ,,
2012 System.map-3.2.0-23-generic-pae ,,
2012 vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic ,,
012 vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae ,,

... sorry about the weird formatting. The "-" wasn't working for bullet points.

Comment: Does the original mount contain an option `errors=remount,ro`?

Comment: Ok, saw it in your mtab. An error occured, you should find it in syslog or kern.log (if it exists). Depending on the type of error you could consider not to remount it readonly.